# Can I do a ctrl-z without the process locking up?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

So lets say I'm executing a command on the CLI and it spawns a GUI and I forget the & at the end.  Now I want my shell back,  so I hit a ctrl-z but the GUI locks up!   Is there any way to do a ctrl-z without locking up the GUI?  I am using Linux with a bash shell,  xorg and gnome. This is an Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [**bg**](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/posix/bg) to put the command that you have stopped in the background.

Comment: It says "no such job"

Comment: When you stop the job you will get something like `[n]+ command stopped` enter `bg n` to backgrounds the job

Comment: Type 'jobs' to see currently running jobs. You should be able to pick the one you need from here. It'll probably be marked 'stopped'.

Comment: and @wzzrd  yeah but its not a job,  its just a command like `firefox`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). It is very useful for this type of thing as well as offering a bunch of other terminal multiplexing functionality that can be very nice.

Comment: I would call screen a lot of things, but a place to start GUI apps from and them (and it) leave them running until eternity wouldn't be one of them. Standard job control fits this job a lot better.

Comment: And why is that? X11 forwarding works perfectly fine through `screen`. The OP wasn't asking how to suspend and resume his application, he really just wanted his shell back, which `screen` will give him.